# undefined method `current_user' ( commontator + devise )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using devise & commontator gems

i don't know what the error about "current_user" when try to "show" the product !!

```
undefined method `current_user' for #<ProductsController:0xd09600c>
```

user model

```
class RegisteredUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    # Registered user can comment on a product
    acts_as_commontator
end
```

product model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Product can be commented on
    acts_as_commontable
end
```

i call show method from ProductsController

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    commontator_thread_show(@product)
  end
end
```

Comment: As you can see from the message, the error is coming from your `ProductsController`. It would be helpful to show the code from that class.

Comment: i added the specific method above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the devise helper based on model name

so it is `current_registered_user` not `current_user`

have to change it in commontator initializer file then restart the server